# Dynamic form Issue in Angular

Tags: forms, angular, angular-forms

**Scenario :**

A form is generated dynamically, I used [this tutorial](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form) to create the form dynamically. When I click "Submit" button, the form value I get in the component is

**ts :**

```
  doSubmitICR(form) {
    console.log(form.value);

  }
```

`form.value` has the following values

```
{
 CaptainPoint:"0",
 Category:"restaurant",
 Description:"Test",
 DisplayDept:"kitchen",
 Group:"restaurant",
 GuestPoint:"0",
 ItemCode:"1",
 ItemName:"Test Item",
 PrintingDept:"frontoffice",
 SalesRate:"3",
 SubGroup:"restaurant",
 TAX1:true,
 TAX2:true,
 TabDisplay:"restaurant",
 Unit:"restaurant"
}
```

TAX1 and TAX2 are dynamic, those form controls were created from a tax table, If the table has TAX3 and TAX4, then instead of TAX1 and TAX2 in the above form, TAX3 and TAX4 form control is generated.

**Issue :**

1. If the TAXs are dynamic, how can I pass these values to Web service say WebAPI2 as a model?
2. Is it possible to filter only the TAX element from the `form.value`?

Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution from alexKhymenko should work well. Alternatively, if the values you want to submit to the API will *always* have the format of `TAX{d}`, where `d` is some combination of digits, you could use the following to get just those values on a request object:

```
let request = {};
Object.keys(form.value).forEach(key => {
    if(/^TAX[\d]+$/.test(key)) 
        request[key] = form.value[key]
});
```